# Second subplot disappearing

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, figure, subplot

I have a weird (and probably simple to solve) problem. I tried to plot (using panel) two plots:

```
a1 = subplot(2,1,1, 'Parent', handles.cpd_plot, 'Position', [0.1, 0.4, 0.85, 0.45]);
a2 = subplot(2,1,2, 'Parent', handles.cpd_plot, 'Position', [0.1, 0.1, 0.85, 0.15]);
```

but after plotting a2, a1 disappears. I see that its some problem with position, when I lift up a1 a bit (`'Position', [0.1, 0.5, 0.85, 0.45]`) its working (but it has to be >= 0.5). Where is the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: does is also happen if you reverse order of subplots?

Comment: no, if I plot a2 and then a1 its fine...

Comment: yea, that's what I thought... so problem solved. Do you still want to know why it happened in the first place?

Comment: sure, what is happening?

Comment: see my answer below, and +1 for spotting this, I don't think this is considered "simple"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it is probably happening because subplot deletes a plot when it is overlapping with the previous plot. I suspect that happens because of conflicting positions values between the subplot tile number (i.e. subplot(2,1,1) etc) that has its own default position, and the position you entered.

So instead of using `subplot(m,l,p, 'position', [ a b c d])`, you can solve this issue by using `subplot` just with the position info as follows:

```
subplot('position',  [0.1, 0.4, 0.85, 0.45])
plot(1:10);
subplot('position', [0.1, 0.1, 0.85, 0.15])
plot(1:10);
```

[image]