# How do I position subplots in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, loops, subplot

I have problem to set the position of subplots. I'm using subplot inside a loop. But when I try to make special position to the subplots it doesn't work. This is my code:

```
h=subplot(2,2,3);
set(h,'position',[0.15 0.15 0.4 0.4]);
plot(d3,S3,'*','Color',colors(i,:));
```

I tried different methods but can't see the third subplot, and sometimes the plot shows only one iteration.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This create 3 subplots. Position is [left bottom width height]). I usually try to make sure that left + width < 1 and that bottom + height < 1 (for the first subplot).

```
figure
set(subplot(3,1,1), 'Position', [0.05, 0.69, 0.92, 0.27])
set(subplot(3,1,2), 'Position', [0.05, 0.37, 0.92, 0.27])
set(subplot(3,1,3), 'Position', [0.05, 0.05, 0.92, 0.27])
```

This works well if you only have 1 column of subplot. For two columns of subplot is use this :

```
figure
subplot(4,2,1)
plot(...)
set(gca, 'OuterPosition', [0, 0.76, 0.49, 0.23])
subplot(4,2,2)
plot(...)
set(gca, 'OuterPosition', [0.48, 0.76, 0.49, 0.23])
subplot(4,2,3)
...
```

Comment: @m_power Ca you tell me how you are calculating the values of the set parameter. I went through the documentation in matlab but could not get the hang of it

Answer (score 3):

It is probably happening because of conflicting positions values between the subplot tile number (i.e. `subplot(2,2,3)` etc) that has its own default position, and the position you entered.

So instead use subplot just with the position info as follows:

```
subplot('position', [0.15 0.15 0.4 0.4])
plot(d3,S3,'*','Color',colors(i,:));
subplot('position', [... ... ... ...])
plot(...);
```

see also [this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273315/matlab-second-subplot-disappearing/14273855#14273855)...

Comment: please add the code you've tried sp we can see what's the issue.

Answer (score 2):

According to [subplot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html)

subplot('Position',[left bottom width height]) creates an axes at the position specified by a four-element vector. The left, bottom, width, and height values are **normalized coordinates** in the range from 0.0 to 1.0.

Also note that left and bottom values are calculated from the left bottom of the figure.

---

Here an example of using subplot in a for loop.

```
figure

% subplot dimension
n1 = 2; % number of rows
n2 = 3; % number of columns

% These values would define the space between the graphs
% if equal to 1 there will be no space between graphs
nw = 0.9; % normalized width
nh = 0.9; % normalized height

for k1 = 1:n1
    for k2 = 1:n2
        subplot(n1,n2,(k1-1)*n2 + k2,...
            'position', [(1-nw)/n2/2 + (k2-1)/n2, (1-nh)/n1/2 + 1-k1/n1,...
            nw/n2 nh/n1]);
        % plot something
        plot(rand(5));
        % turn off the labels if you want
        set(gca, 'XTick', []);
        set(gca, 'YTick', []);
    end
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In Matlab 2016b: The first plot gets resized, when the second plot is generated and remains too small. What must be changed to get it working in Matlab 2016b?