# How to remove margins around subplots in matlab?

Tags: matlab, margins, subplot

How to remove margins around subplots in matlab?

**ATTENTION**

`subaxis` does not work.

`set(gca, 'LooseInset', get(gca,'TightInset'))` does not work

**SAMPLE**

The following code:

```
%set(gca,'LooseInset',get(gca,'TightInset'));

rgb1=imread('..\FruitSample_small.png');
original1 = applycform(rgb1, makecform('srgb2lab'));
original1_L = original1(:,:,1);
original1_a = original1(:,:,2);
original1_b = original1(:,:,3);
rgb1=applycform(original1, makecform('lab2srgb'));


subaxis(5,4,1);
imshow(rgb1);
subaxis(5,4,2);
imshow(original1_L);
subaxis(5,4,3);
imshow(original1_a);
subaxis(5,4,4);
imshow(original1_b);
```

displays

[image]

which is not acceptable.

Image is squared (as you see). While left and right margins can be explained by maintaining aspect ration, the top and the bottom margins are baseless.

**UPDATE**

Please note that "already given" answer does not work for me.

Comment: consider this FEX option instead, http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27991-tight-subplot

Comment: You can also use `subplot` and change their position manually.
Refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16764477/1698972) for example.

Comment: yet another option is to use montage: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/montage.html but you need the Image Processing Toolbox for that...