# Why do independent subplots overwrite each other? Why is the order of plotting important?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I'm writing a gui which requires to exactly position some subplots:

```
h = figure('Units','pixels','Position',[1920 432  1881 982]*0.5);

ax.VSize = 815.3800*0.5
ax.VOffset = 48.9228*0.5
ax.HSize = 1.8063e+03*0.5
ax.HOffset = 56.4480*0.5

subax.VSize = 0.33*(ax.VSize-3*ax.VOffset);
subax.HSize = ax.HSize;
subplot(313,'units','pixels','Position',[ax.HOffset ax.VOffset ax.HSize subax.VSize ])
subplot(312,'units','pixels','Position',[ax.HOffset 2*ax.VOffset+subax.VSize subax.HSize subax.VSize])
subplot(311,'units','pixels','Position',[ax.HOffset 3*ax.VOffset+2*subax.VSize subax.HSize subax.VSize])
```

which gives me the desired results:

[image]

However, when I change the order of the subplots to:

```
subplot(311,'units','pixels','Position',[ax.HOffset 3*ax.VOffset+2*subax.VSize subax.HSize subax.VSize])
subplot(312,'units','pixels','Position',[ax.HOffset 2*ax.VOffset+subax.VSize subax.HSize subax.VSize])
subplot(313,'units','pixels','Position',[ax.HOffset ax.VOffset ax.HSize subax.VSize ])
```

I just get the last subplot plotted:

[image]

I really don't see why this is happening? **Why do the subplots overwrite each other?**

Unfortunately the order of plotting is important to me, so how can I fix this?

---

Funnily, I can't reproduce the problem with another number or arrangement of subplots, like:

```
subax.VSize = 0.5*(ax.VSize-2*ax.VOffset);
subax.HSize = 0.5*(ax.HSize-2*ax.HOffset);
subplot(221,'units','pixels','Position',[ax.HOffset 2*ax.VOffset+subax.VSize subax.HSize subax.VSize])
subplot(222,'units','pixels','Position',[2*ax.HOffset+subax.HSize 2*ax.VOffset+subax.VSize subax.HSize subax.VSize])
subplot(223,'units','pixels','Position',[ax.HOffset ax.VOffset subax.HSize subax.VSize ])
subplot(224,'units','pixels','Position',[2*ax.HOffset+subax.HSize ax.VOffset subax.HSize subax.VSize ])
```

[image]

Comment: I can't duplicate this issue on R2014b (OS X). What platform and version are you using?

Comment: Matlab R2015b on Windows 7. It seems to have to do with [this](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/141329-subplots-destroys-the-axis-properties).

Comment: Related problem: [Second subplot disappearing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273315/second-subplot-disappearing/14273855#14273855).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is still not entirely clear to me, but [**here**](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/141329-subplots-destroys-the-axis-properties) is said:

> Per the doc, if you overwrite the area of a subplot, it deletes the
>   existing one and creates a new one. AFAIK there's no way to avoid this
>   behavior. There's an example of an overlaying axes with subplot() in
>   the documentation; note that it avoids this by specifying that axes
>   with axes, not another subplot.
>
> You can probably get by with yours if you only refer to the two axes
>   with the saved handles once they're created.

The suggested solution also works in my case:

```
s(1) = subplot(311,'units','pixels')
s(2) = subplot(312,'units','pixels')
s(3) = subplot(313,'units','pixels')

set(s(1),'Position',[ax.HOffset 3*ax.VOffset+2*subax.VSize subax.HSize subax.VSize])
set(s(2),'Position',[ax.HOffset 2*ax.VOffset+subax.VSize subax.HSize subax.VSize])
set(s(3),'Position',[ax.HOffset ax.VOffset ax.HSize subax.VSize ])
```

However, as I specify the exact position of every subplot, the whole purpose of subplots is gone, so I will just use:

```
axes('units','pixels','Position',floor([ax.HOffset 3*ax.VOffset+2*subax.VSize subax.HSize subax.VSize]));
axes('units','pixels','Position',floor([ax.HOffset 2*ax.VOffset+subax.VSize subax.HSize subax.VSize]));
axes('units','pixels','Position',floor([ax.HOffset ax.VOffset 0.96*hsize subax.VSize]));
```

Weird problem anyhow.