# Can I dynamicaly add change `subplot` dimensions?

Tags: matlab

Can I dynamicaly add change `subplot` dimensions? For example, I have `subplot(2,1,1)` and `subplot(2,1,2)`, but now I want to keep those 2 columns, and add 3rd one so I can do `subplot(3,1,1)` without loosing previous 2 plots. Would that be possible?

Comment: If you want to change the position of subplots, its often better not use subplots at all. I guess it's a duplicate question of [**this one**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846300/why-do-independent-subplots-overwrite-each-other-why-is-the-order-of-plotting-i), isn't it?

Comment: Well, re-reading your question, I think you want something different. But please provide some example code to play around!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code:

```
figure
x = linspace(-5,5);
ha1 = subplot(2,1,1)
plot(x, sin(x))
title('First subplot')

ha2 = subplot(2,1,2)
plot(x, sin(2*x))
title('Second subplot')

subplot(3,1,2,ha1)
subplot(3,1,3,ha2)
subplot(3,1,1,'align')
title('New First subplot')
```